# cakephp shell not working like webpage

Tags: shell, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have baked load of files and in the web browser they work fine. In particular I have tables:

```
filters       HABTM items
items         HABTM filters
filters_items BT    filters, items
```

now in my Shell I have the following:

```
class xShell extends AppShell {
  public $uses = array('filter', 'filter_item', 'item');

  public function preload() {
    $allFilters = $this->filter_item->findAll(null, 'DISTINCT filter_item.filter_id');
  }
}
```

but when I run

```
Console/cake x preload
```

I get the error:

```
Database table filter_items for model filter_item was not found
```

so I set the following in the filter_item model:

```
public $useTable = 'filters_items';
```

and still the same error.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,

It wasn't obvious in the docs but you can't actually search over the joining table. So you can search over Item and Filter but not FilterItem.

Sorry for the false alarm.